# What are the best examples of accessible highlighting online?

Tags: navigation, accessibility, highlight

## I'm seeking Accessible Highlighting online and not seeing much.

I'm well versed in high-end accessibility, but I am having trouble finding ANY examples of accessible highlight, let alone best-of-breed samples.

Before I launch into reinventing the wheel, can anyone give me a few example links I can test out?

### The requirements include the following.

1. Must be screen reader accessible.
2. Must be delete-able as well as add-able.
3. Must be keyboard accessible to a non-screen reader as well. (not always the case)

Anyone have an example they can point me to?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't have/know any special solution here. So just a braindump: Different voices for different classes? Some special audio sequences (e.g. 3 tones at the beginning and 3 tones at the end played in reverse order)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean when you say "highlighting?"

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to build? Is it for an editable area, or static text? Can you annotate what's highlighted? If editable, can't you just provide a markup shortcut?  If it's on the web, you may find this [hack to make `<mark>` more accessible](http://adrianroselli.com/2017/12/tweaking-text-level-styles.html) and an extension of the idea for [the `<del>` and `<ins>` elements](http://adrianroselli.com/2017/12/tweaking-text-level-styles.html), and use something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You might like this GitHub repository which is an application of how to make the syntax highlighting accessible. 
Link: https://github.com/ericwbailey/a11y-syntax-highlighting

Comment: If I got Ryan's intent right, he is searching for a non-visual way of highlighting. So the given examples do not really help - or did I get something wrong?